# I am trying to populate the kendo grid with the JSON data received from the controller but failing to do so

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I am using a kendo grid and using jQuery selector and trying to set the data for the grid like this:

```js
  $(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
      var url = '@Url.Action("GetAllEmp")';
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result) {
          if (result) {
            if (result.isSuccess) {
              var grid = $('#grid').data.kendoGrid();
              grid.dataSource.data(result.data);

            } else {


            }
          }
        }
      });

    });


  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I did put the result data into one of a paragraph in the body and found that I was getting the JSON data from the controller.

The problem that I found using F12 in the browsers developer tools sources was:

[Browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEkv4.jpg)

It says:

> "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data.kendoGrid is not a function"

Can anyone tell me what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `kendoGrid` is not a function, you have to write it without parentheses.

eg. `var grid = $('#grid').data.kendoGrid;`

Comment: $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(result.data);     -This solved my problem and it was also Kendo.mvc.dll versioning problem.